# Save Many-To-Many Relationship in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have two table `Product` and `Order` that `Many-To-Many` to each other. so, i created one other Table Middle of them `order_table`.

I try to save relationship `many-to-many`, but i got error `unit_price` doesnt have a default value.

**in Product Model**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'description', 'status'
    ];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Order::class);
    }
```

**in Order Model**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'description', 'ref_no', 'customer_id', 'description', 'active'
    ];


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Product::class);
    }
```

**And in Order_Product Schema**

```
        Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->double('unit_price');
            $table->integer('quantity')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

**In ProductController**

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required',
            'description' => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $product = new Product();
        $product->name = $request->input('name');
        $product->price = $request->input('price');
        $product->status = $request->input('status');
        $product->description = $request->input('description');
        $product->save();

        $orders = new \App\Order();
        $orders->unit_price = $request->unit_price;
        $product->orders()->attach($orders);

        return response()->json(['created' => true]);
    }
```

I'll appreciate of all ur help.... Thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate the Data to insure it exists.

```
$data = $this->validate($request, [
'unit_price' => 'required|numeric'
]);
$data['unit_price'];
```

Use the get method and specify a fallback

```
$product->orders()->attach($order, [
'unit_price' => $request->get('unit_price', 0)
]);
```

Fill the pivot using "only" for ease of use once you have it worked out:

```
$product->orders()->attach(
$order, $request->only(['unit_price'])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`I got error unit_price doesn't have a default value.`

This is a Database issue. Please set a `default value` for `unit_price` column.